# Need to print the Countdown using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I thought about wanting to know when the next episode of my favorite anime show is gonna be by doing a little bit of web scraping, and searching that specific anime. Then printing out the next episode countdown from the id="nextEpisodeCountDown" in a span tag.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://kissanime.ru/")

time.sleep(15)
search = driver.find_element_by_id("keyword")
search.send_keys("Rent a Girlfriend")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(10)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("nextEpisodeCountDown")
print(element)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is here. You basically just said "I had this idea and here's the code I wrote to do it". I'm gonna go out on a limb and assume you're asking for help making this work because it isn't working as you expected it to? The code you posted works just fine to accomplish the goal you stated with perhaps one issue. I'm guessing the issue you're having is what's being printed out with your code is something like

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="567cb03b2d0f311ccf81166ff58c62c4", element="92669594-5987-48e7-8cd1-1572a68fc34e")>
```

and the output you wanted was

```
06 days 19h:11m
```

going with this assumption what you need to do is alter your print statement to say `print(element.text)`. When you use `element = driver.find_element_by_id("nextEpisodeCountDown")` what is returned is that element object and you are looking to print the text of that element thus you need to write `element.text`. Hope this helps and if not perhaps edit your question to be more clear what it is you're asking.